# Add to CONCAT() if a column is = 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get a SQL query to concat "FreeShipping" to a string only if I have a '1' in `FreeShipping` field
This is the current SQL I have but I have no clue how to use the IF statement and add the `concat()` function

Im I suposed to make the if select between two `concat()` function?

```
SELECT
    `Id`
FROM
    `product_products` as pp
WHERE
    CONCAT(
        `Id`,
        ' ',
        (SELECT `Name` FROM `product_brands` WHERE `Id` = pp.BrandId),
        ' ',
        `ModelNumber`,
        ' ',
        `Title`
    )
LIKE :SearchStr AND isActive = 1;
```

Expected result is only Id of products, I want to select the products by Searching for "FreeShipping"

The `:SearchStr` is a variable

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your right, It was pretty hard to understand what im asking I just edited my question. What im expecting is only ids that i get from the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are filtering by that concatenated string, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    `Id`
FROM
    `product_products` as pp
WHERE
    CONCAT(
        `Id`,
        ' ',
        (SELECT `Name` FROM `product_brands` WHERE `Id` = pp.BrandId),
        ' ',
        `ModelNumber`,
        ' ',
        `Title`,
        IF(`FreeShipping` = 1, " FreeShipping", "")
    )
LIKE :SearchStr AND isActive = 1;
```

If `FreeShipping = 1` then concat " FreeShipping" (with leading space). If not, then concat with an empty string.

Comment: Cool, Thats whats i needed, I was under impresion the only way I was able to do it was by making a condition to use either one concat or the other resulting in a very long query for nothing!   Thanks!